# How to count how many string in a column

Tags: r, string

I have a datasets with a column "amenities" and I want to count how many amenities in each row.

```
> airbnbT$amenities[1]
[1] ["Essentials", "Refrigerator", "Shampoo", "TV", "Dedicated workspace", "Hangers", "Iron", "Long term stays allowed", "Dishes and silverware", "First aid kit", "Free parking on premises", "Hair dryer", "Patio or balcony", "Washer", "Dryer", "Cooking basics", "Coffee maker", "Private entrance", "Hot water", "Fire extinguisher", "Wifi", "Air conditioning", "Hot tub", "Kitchen", "Microwave", "Oven", "Smoke alarm"]
14673 Levels: ["Air conditioning", "Baby bath", "Long term stays allowed", "Baby monitor"] ...

> class(airbnbT$amenities[1])
[1] "factor"
```

Here for row 1,  there are 27 amenities.
Is there a way to count the comma in each row "," ? This way would count the numbers of amenities.

Comment: May be this : `length(airbnbT$amenities[1])-1`

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_count` from the `stringr` package. You will need to add 1 since there will be one fewer comma than the number of amenities:

```
library(stringr)

airbnbT$amenities_count = str_count(airbnbT$amenities,",") + 1
```